# Monitor incoming TCP/UDP flood attack and graph it

Tags: monitoring, ddos, network-traffic, graph, flooding

I'm preparing a presentation on a security issue and want to include a demonstration. It won't be in real time, I just need to show some pictures of the results.

I have some VPSes that will perform a tcp or udp flood attack simiultanesly on another specific server (Debian/Ubuntu), all of them owned by me of course. Something like a tiny scale DDoS attack.

I want some suggestions for existing tools or new programs to be installed on the target server (Debian/Ubuntu server distro) that can monitor and produce traffic graphs and related charts so I can present the network state before and after the attack.

*I don't want to mitigate or stop the attack*, but to show the results of it and if possible in a fancy way.

I'd appreciate every idea and suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Also the answer at #security -> http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/monitor-incoming-tcp-udp-flood-attack-and-graph-it

Answer (score 3):

[`ntop`](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/) will graph the stats you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

To graph the network bandwidth usage you can use for example [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) or [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/).